# How can I check if the background color of a button is [color]? (.NET MAUI - Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, maui

This is my code (.NET MAUI - Visual Studio):

#### File *Mainpage.xaml.cs*:

```csharp
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

namespace App;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ......

    private void LockerClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;

        if (clickedButton.BackgroundColor == Color.Blue)
        {
            // Action
        }
    }
}
```

#### File *Mainpage.cs*

```html
......
<Button x:Name="LockerButton" Clicked="LockerClicked" Text="⌨" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="40" TextColor="#007070" FontAttributes="Bold" CornerRadius="100" BackgroundColor="White"/>
......
```

However, I get a:

> Compiler Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'Color.Blue'

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Colors`, not `Color`:

```
if (clickedButton.BackgroundColor == Colors.Blue)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can follow these steps:

Get the current background color of the button:
You need to access the BackgroundColor property of the button control. This property represents the current background color of the button.

Compare the background color with the target color:
Once you have obtained the background color of the button, you can compare it with the color you want to check.
Here's a code example to illustrate the process in C#:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxBA0.png)
Replace **myButton** with the name of your button control in the above code. Also, ensure that you have the necessary using directives for **Microsoft.Maui.Controls** in your code file.

This code snippet checks if the background color of the button **(myButton)** matches the **targetColor** (in this case, the color is set to red). If they match, you can perform specific actions or logic as required. If they don't match, you can handle it differently.

Remember that colors can be defined using RGBA or hexadecimal notation, so make sure the **targetColor** is in the same format as the **BackgroundColor** property of the button.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Zeeshan.ayyub!

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).